# how to override a Core Customer Model in a local module in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, model, ce-1.9.2.0

I am try to override Function public **`function validate()`** in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`

To Restrict user registration by email domain i can do this by change directly in Function public **`function validate()`** in **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php** but I need to override it in codepool.

With Creating module in codepool :

> /app/code/local/Codefire/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Customer>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Codefire_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <customer>
              <rewrite>
                  <customer>Codefire_Customer_Model_Customer</customer>
              </rewrite>
          </customer>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

> /app/etc/modules/Codefire_Customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Codefire_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Codefire/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Overrite Customer model
 */

class Codefire_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer{

    /**
     * Validate customer attribute values.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate() {
     echo 'I am here'; die;
   }
```

I need call this function when do new registration.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Could you check if you don't have any other module rewriting the same model ? Also did you flush the cache ?

Comment: I have clear cache and how can check rewriting the same model ? and i work on linux machine.

Comment: Try disabling every other local and community module and see if your validate code is getting called. If it is that means you've got another module rewriting the same model.

Comment: Okey, but it is the first module to overwrite model

Comment: @rajeevG is your magento shop having third party extension installed and active?

Comment: I try after disabled Cm_RedisSession and Phoenix_Moneybookers but did not working.

Comment: Please any one let me know soluntion

Comment: Can you see your module in System>Configuration>Advanced ?

Answer (score 1):

**/app/etc/modules/Codefire_Customer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool> //codePool and not codepool
            <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends> //you have forgot the depends
        </Codefire_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

With this config, Magento load first **Mage_Customer** then **Codefire_Customer**

Comment: @rajeevG Please accept the answer that you find helpful

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Customer Model class with below code:

```
<?php
class Codefire_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer{

    /**
     * Validate customer attribute values.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate() {
     echo 'I am here'; die;
   }
}
```

Its seems you missed closing "**}**" of your **Codefire_Customer_Model_Customer**

This might be the root cause of your issue.

Comment: by mistake remove "}" time of posting

Comment: Same code is working for me ... :)

Comment: I waiting yr response how this is working yr end please let me know in which OS. and give me some steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if Mage_Customer_Model_Customer is already extended by another class?

If there is another class that is already extending the class that you are trying to overwrite then it may not work. If yes then instead of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer class you might need to extend another class and make changes in config file accordingly.

Other reason could be you are missing below code in your **/app/etc/modules/Codefire_Customer.xml**

```
        <depends>
            <Mage_Customer />
        </depends>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do this in a custom module? If not you could duplicate `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` into `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` and alter the validate function there.

Comment: You should never do this!